# Повторять функцию не начиная с начала

Tags: python

Есть такая функция:

```
def func():
    while True:
        result = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/items?key=XXXXXXXX').json()
        if result['items'] != 'null':
            m = len(result['items'])
            for o in range(m):
                classid = result['items'][o]['classid']
            for x in range(m):
                itemid = result['items'][x]['item_id']
                hashname = result['items'][x]['market_hash_name']
                print(hashname)
                time.sleep(2)
                rewss = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/search-item-by-hash-name?key=XXXXL&hash_name=' + hashname).json()
                if result['items'][x]['position'] != 1:
                    if rewss['data'] != []:
                        k = len(rewss['data'])
                        for j in range(k):
                            firstprice = min(rewss['data'], key=lambda x: x['price'])['price']
                            cla = min(rewss['data'], key=lambda x: x['price'])['class']
                            newprais = float(firstprice) - 1.0
                            time.sleep(3)
                            if hashname == rewss['data'][j]['market_hash_name']:
                                newprice1 = str(newprais)
                                currency = result['items'][x]['currency']
                                time.sleep(3)
                                r = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/set-price?key=3F5XXXXX&item_id=' + itemid + '&price=' + newprice1 + '&cur=' + currency + '&')
                                print(r.text)
```

Если в конце нет `func()`, то код застывает тут,если же есть - код начинается сначала.Я хочу сделать так,чтобы код не застывал в конце,но и не повторялся.Помогите изменить строение пожалуйста.Может через return можно сделать новую функцию,но уверен,что есть способы легче.

Comment: Что делает Ваша программа? Мне кажется, что `while True` тут лишнее.

Comment: Программа меняет значение в у всех элементов списка,цена которых ниже моей.Я хочу чтобы она анализировала цены и если цена ниже моей меняла ее и продолжала работать со следующими элементами, а не начинала сначала

Comment: ну так удалите проанализированный элемент из списка элементов.

Comment: не знаю как это можно сделать(